# Charting Non-Contiguous Data Using Declared Range Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart using non-contiguous data, and the code I had seemed to work. I get the run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed, which leads me to believe I am not qualifying the ranges correctly at some point, but I can't figure out where. The failure point is the last line where I am setting the source data for the chart. I'm sure it will turn out to be something trivial, but a fresh set of eyes always helps. Hopefully I have given enough information, but I will be sure to add more if needed. TIA

```
Dim ComponentNames  As Range
Dim ChartTitle      As Range
Dim MaxTime         As Integer
Dim ChartL          As Long
Dim ChartT          As Long
Dim DegDataRange    As Range
Dim LabelDataRange  As Range
Dim LineDataRangeX  As Range
Dim LineDataRangeY  As Range
Dim LineLabelRange  As Range
Dim DegSum          As Long
Dim CombinedRange   As String

Set LineDataRangeX = DataSheet.Range("$X$34:$X$35")
Set LineDataRangeY = DataSheet.Range("$W$34:$W$35")
Set LineLabelRange = DataSheet.Range("$V$34")

Set ComponentNames = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, CDLineLabelCol), _
    DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, CDLineLabelCol))                      'Define the range for COMPONENT names
Set ChartTitle = InputSheet.Range("$D$8")                                       'Define the range to get the CHART TITLE
MaxTime = 360 / WorksheetFunction.Min(DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, _
    CDScaleCol), DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, CDScaleCol))) + MaxEnable 'Store the MAX TIME in a variable

For i = 1 To Range(ChartCell).Column - 1
    ChartL = ChartL + OutputSheet.Columns(i).Width                                       'Store the A1 Column width for Chart Placement
Next i
For i = 1 To Range(ChartCell).Row - 1
    ChartT = ChartT + OutputSheet.Rows(i).Height
Next i

Set DegDataRange = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, CDFirstMasterCol), DataSheet.Cells(WriteRow - 1, CDFirstMasterCol))
For i = CDFirstMasterCol + 2 To CDFinalMasterCol Step 2
    Set DegDataRange = Union(DegDataRange, DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, i), DataSheet.Cells(WriteRow - 1, i)))
Next i

Set LabelDataRange = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, CDFirstLabelCol), DataSheet.Cells(WriteRow - 1, CDFirstLabelCol))
For i = CDFirstLabelCol + 2 To CDFinalLabelCol Step 2
    Set LabelDataRange = Union(LabelDataRange, DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(CDRow, i), DataSheet.Cells(WriteRow - 1, i)))
Next i

'Define a CHART object, created to aligned left with the A-Column, 1-Row below last Data point
Dim TimingChart As Chart

Set TimingChart = OutputSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=ChartL, Width:=MaxTime * 3, Top:=ChartT, Height:=(WriteRow - CDRow) * 80).Chart

With TimingChart                    'Set the TIMINGCHART variable as the object of interest for convenience
    .HasTitle = True                'Turn on the CHART TITLE
    .ChartTitle.Text = ChartTitle   'Assign previously stored CHART TITLE
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked     'Set the Chart Type to be BAR-STACKED

    .SetSourceData Source:=DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Name & "!" & DegDataRange.Address & "," & LineDataRangeY.Address), PlotBy:=xlColumns  'Fill the data fields of the bar chart with the compiled DEGREE range
    '...Do other things with TimingChart
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're including `DataSheet.Name & "!"` inside the `Range` call.

Comment: @BigBen I left it in there because it worked before with it. I did try without it as I realize that it is unnecessary, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: What's the result of `Debug.Print DegDataRange.Addess` in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen You know, I could've sworn I had tried that but apparently not. Thank you for putting me out of my misery.

Comment: There's a 255 character limit on the address passed to `Range`, so you can use `Union` instead. I had previously proposed `Union`... does that work?

Comment: @BigBen The Union comment you deleted worked for me, but knowing that there is a character limit on the address I will probably have to make the data contiguous for DegDataRange anyway.

Comment: You don't need to do that, as long as you don't surpass the maximum number of areas in a `Range` and remember to use `Union`.

Comment: @BigBen Okay, I think I understand now. Thank you again for your help. Is there a way I can up vote your answer?

Comment: I didn't answer but pointed to a similar question that touches on the 255-character limit and the use of `Union`. No need to upvote, happy to help.